# generating truth tables in php with position

Tags: java, php, loops, if-statement, tags

I need to write a function that :
have 6 variable:
it can be or empty or value (other system will send empty or value For each variable)

```
var 1 = 
var 2 = 
var 3 = 
var 4 = 
var 5 = 
var 6 =
```

I need a function that returns all variable that different then empty
for exp:

```
var 1 = 
var 2 = "good"
var 3 = 
var 4 = "samting"
var 5 = 
var 6 =
```

it returns the values that are not empty.
for exp var 2 and var 4

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was sorta' following you until you got to the last sentence. What do you want? Also, how do you generate a "truth table" of 1,2,3? A truth table, by definition, implies binary, which means that it won't have digits such as 2 or 3.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what's the input and what should be the output?

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: Can you paragraph your question in term of function scope? I mean, you need to write a function that will receive X and it will return Y, for example. Try to extract your question from terms like "checkbox" or "I click to..." because these concepts are details that should not affect the implementation.

Comment: i edit the question